# How do I average monthly data to get yearly values in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1871-01 | 4.5 |
| 1871-02 | 10.7 |
| 1871-03 | 8.9 |
| 1871-04 | 1.3 |

all the way to 2021-12.

how do I get the average value for each year in Python? For example, the 1871 average would be the average of all of the values from 1871-01 to 1871-1 and I would like it for all years from 1871-2021.
...            ...

Answer (score 1):

Make a numpy array with the values, reshape and use np.mean.

Example with only 3 years worth of "data"

```
import numpy as np

values=np.random.normal(0,1,36)
yearly_avgs=np.mean(values.reshape((len(values)//12,12)),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

given your data is in a pandas dataframe called df:

```py
>>> df
    Date        Value
0   1871-01     4.5
1   1871-02     10.7
2   1871-03     8.9
3   1871-04     1.3
4   1872-02     1.5
5   1872-03     15.9
6   1872-04     7.3
>>> year_df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y')).mean()
>>> year_df.index = year_df.index.year
>>> year_df
Date    Value
1871    6.35
1872    8.233333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the what format the data is being given to you.  Is it json? csv? If you already know how to import and read the data with python.. you just need to assign the years to variables and average them.  (x1 + x2 + x3) / (number of averaged variables)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get average of all the data according to monthly average for years. In this method there's no need to set `date` as **index** and will return single level **dataframe** as shown in output.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("1871-01","2021-12",freq="M"),"val":np.random.randint(10,100,[1811])}) # 1811 months
df[df["date"].dt.year==1871].mean() # 57.666667
df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df["date"],freq="y"))["val"].mean().reset_index()
```

Above method will return same output even if `date` feature is of `str` data type.

Following below will return the same output given the column/feature is `date` type.

```
df.groupby(df["date"].dt.year)["val"].mean().reset_index()
```

Output `.head()`:

|  | date | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1871 | 57.666667 |
| 1 | 1872 | 58.916667 |
| 2 | 1873 | 52.416667 |
| 3 | 1874 | 41.666667 |
| 4 | 1875 | 57.583333 |